# How to create a controllable moss material for a photoscanned object?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image]I'd like to apply a layer of moss over my photoscanned object that's realistic and doesn't take a performance hit.

Comment: Could you show some reference images of type of moss you want to achieve? And what "controllable" means in this case?

Comment: i'd like just a simple moss that can be applied on any object and be "controlled" by adjusting a value. say 0 for no moss,to 1 covered in a lot of moss

Answer (score 1):

realistic is relative and increadibly difficult to achive when compared to photoscanned

you can use particles and get very realistic result, but a heavy performance hit

or you use vertex paint, or mask paint to mask out the areas where you want the moss to then procedually add the moss in the material editor with nodes. not very realistic, but still quick and easy

but the best would be to paint the textures, this will take the lowest ammount of performace but the highest ammount of work

Comment: If I was to paint the textures I wouldn't be able to control the level of moss that was on the rock correct? I would just have a rock variant with moss on it?

Comment: Then you need to create it procedurally, I have once created a node group where you can control a lot of parameters where the moss should be but it's a performance hit. Thing is, you want something rather impossible, realistic, lots of control and no performance hit are biting each other

Comment: Sorry let me clarify then. I don't mind the performance hit. I just don't want it to be such a hit that it's more of a inconvenience than a convenience

Comment: Then you need to make it procedurally, most control, randomness option and realistic if done good with little performance hit, depending on the complexity (realism + controllability)